# Marketing Cloud not registering all the devices for push notifications [iOS]

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, ios, push, cloud

We have a problem with the push notifications on iOS devices. 
Firstly, we developed a new mobile app with the problem that it did not send the System Token, so users entered in MobilePush without SystemToken. Therefore, we could not send push notifications to this users.
Finally, we managed to solve this error and we published a new app in the Store with the solution but now, only the new installations of the app are registering in Marketing Cloud. Users who update the new version of the app are not registering in Marketing Cloud, so users have to reinstall the app ir order to get the push notifications.

  Is MC not allowing to update the systemToken for users with registered in previous versions?

Comment: I have realized that an automation was deleting contacts without SystemToken. Maybe for this reason MC is not registering the deviceid again?

Comment: We have found that many push contacts were deleted. 
In the previous version of the app we did not receive the system token, and we decided to delete that  push contacts.
Could this deletion affect the registration of users who update the new version of the app and they cannot register again unless doing a new app installation and getting a new deviceID ?

Comment: The only "delete" is via a GDPR delete, so you've probably "permanently" disabled the application for those customers. Open a support ticket.